# how to plot train and test together using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot (y_train, y_test)and then (y_train_pred, y_test_pred) together in one gragh and i use the following code to do so

```
#plot 
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.plot(y_pred)
plt.plot(y_train)
plt.plot(train)
plt.legend(['y_train','y_train_pred', 'y_test', 'y_test_pred'])
```

Running the above gives me the below graph

[image]

But this isn't want i want. I want it in way that it's continous as show below (**y_test** continues/starts after **y_train** and ***y_pred starts*** after ***y_train_pred***)

[image]

Any help will be great.

Comment: provide explicit x-values

Comment: @PaulH what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `x` argument:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_pred)) + len(y_train),y_test)
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_pred)) + len(y_train), y_pred)
plt.plot(y_train)
plt.plot(train)

# you seemed to mess up the labels
plt.legend(['y_test', 'y_test_pred', 'y_train','y_train_pred'])
```

Comment: this gives a value error `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (157,) and (52, 1)` on the first line

Comment: @Tamarie I messed up `train` and `test`. See update.

Comment: how do i change the colors for all the lines? seems i can only change 2 id i add color argument at the end

Comment: you can pass `color=` to `plt.plot`.

Comment: `plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_pred)) + len(y_train),y_test, color='steelblue')` and `plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_pred)) + len(y_train), y_pred, color='grey')` only changes the y_test and y_test_pred. but i also want to change y_train and y_train_pred

Comment: I am trying to implement to same thing and this just helped a lot but 1 question, I want to plot this for multiple folds so am using subplots to view them all together. The only issue I have is that they are now not sharing the same Xaxis. How do I get them to share axis using your code ? I tried sharex but each plot has it’s on Xaxis still